# Importing a Greek letter from the "eulervm" package, but not the whole package

Tags: fonts, symbols

I'd like to import a capital delta from the `eulervm` package without importing the whole package. I've tried to follow the instructions given by Alan Munn in [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/), but I wasn't able to find the "loading-settings" for `eulervm` on my own, and I got stuck.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by “calligraphic capital delta”? There's no calligraphic Greek in `eulervm`; are you meaning the calligraphic capital “D”, instead?

Comment: I just mean the capital delta shown at the bottom of page 3 in http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/fonts/eulervm/doc/latex/eulervm/eulervm.pdf.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to import the symbol as text; the Delta is at slot 1 in the font. Using `\text` ensures the symbol will scale in sub/superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\euDelta}{%
  \text{\usefont{U}{zeur}{m}{n}\symbol{1}}%
}

%% remove the following three lines if you
%% don't want to scale the symbol
\makeatletter
\newcommand\zeu@Scale{1.05}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\Delta\euDelta$
\end{document}
```

[image]